# CSS Menu Drop down expanding Div Container

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu

Having problems with my CSS menu drop-down as instead of overlapping the containers its expanding them. Probably very simple oversight but can't find the answer (closest match was [Div within li not expanding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14157457/div-within-li-not-expanding) but the suggestion of putting an absolute position to the submenu class didn't work). Also there is no JS.

Here is the JSFiddle Link : http://jsfiddle.net/KNBLC/

HTML

```
<body>
<div class="secondary-content-6col">
     <h1><span class="white">Headline</span></h1>

    <ul class="yellow-call-to-action">
        <li><a href="#">1. Select a Product <img src="../img/arrow-small.png" alt="arrow"/></a>

            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Item 1</a>

                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Item 2</a>

                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Item 3</a>

                </li>
            </ul>
            <!--- 1st column Footer -->
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this in your css

`.secondary-content-6col {height:150px;}`

You need to set a height to that div, else it wil see the height as

`height:auto;`